# Metabox Not Showing the Selected Item

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type, in which I created 2 taxonomies for.
I am utilizing the `meta_box_cb` to change the default checkbox to radio lists because I need to allow only one item to be selected.

While this all works (note, it even "saves" the proper values), I cannot seem to get the second taxonomy to show what was selected, though I can see that it is saved in the database when I query the `_postmeta` table for it.

**Screenshot of database records:** [image]
**Screenshot of what is shown:**

[image: http://prntscr.com/iol525]

Here is the code to register the taxonomies:

```
private function create_the_term( $term_name, $term_label ) {
    register_taxonomy(
        $term_name, array( 'gyo_alerts', ), 
        array(
            'hierarchical'=> true, 
            'label' => $term_label,
            'singular_label' => $term_label,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'public' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'capabilities'      => array( // we need most of the display options, but do not want these to be edittable
                'assign_terms' => 'manage_options',
                'edit_terms'   => 'god',
                'manage_terms' => 'god',
            ),
            'show_in_quick_edit' => false,
            'meta_box_cb' => function( $post, $box ) { // change these to single-select
                $the_term = $box['args']['taxonomy'];
                $terms = get_terms( $the_term, array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
                $post  = get_post( );
                $_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post -> ID, $the_term );

                $name  = '';

                if ( ! is_wp_error( $_terms ) ) {
                    if ( isset( $_terms[0] ) ) {

                        $name = wp_list_pluck( $_terms, 'name' )[0];

                    }
                }

                var_dump( $name );
                echo '<hr />';
                var_dump( $post->ID );
                echo '<hr />';
                var_dump( $the_term );
                echo '<hr />';
                var_dump( $_terms );

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                    ?>
                    <label title='<?php esc_attr_e( $term -> name ); ?>'>
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php esc_attr_e( $the_term ); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $term -> name ); ?>" <?php checked( $term -> name, $name ); ?> />
                    <span><?php esc_html_e( $term -> name ); ?></span>
                    </label><br />
                    <?php
                }
                unset( $terms, $_terms );
            },
        )
    );
}
```

How it is being called:

```
    // Status
    $this -> create_the_term( 'alert_type', 'Status' );

    // Alert Activity
    $this -> create_the_term( 'alert_activity', 'Activity' );
```

It is like the `wp_get_post_terms` is getting fired off for only the first taxonomy... and completely forgets about the second.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same exact effect happens if I remove the `meta_box_cb`, and attempt to simply create them outside of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking deeper into why `$_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post -> ID, $the_term );` was not geting populated made me realize that these are not saving as `termmeta`, but rather as `postmeta`

Once I change that to `$post_saved_terms = get_post_meta( $post -> ID, $which );` it started working